# Making calls to Facebook API with PHP SDK after Javascript SDK authentication

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-opengraph, facebook-oauth

Facebook's [guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/) on authenticating with the javascript SDK says:

"The Facebook SDK for JavaScript automatically handles access token storage and tracking of login status, so apps using it do not need to create their own mechanisms for doing so, and can proceed to making API calls."

Most of my code will be server-side PHP, but I plan on using this Javascript SDK for authentication. Ideally, I'd like my users to log in as little as possible. From what I understand, that means that once I get a token I should convert it to a long-lived token and store that token in my database for calls over the next 59 days. At that point, I should renew the token before it expires and repeat until the user de-authorizes my application.

I don't understand how I can take advantage of the fact that Facebook is keeping track of my tokens for me. Won't I need the token to make calls using the PHP SDK? If not- what's the difference between PHP calls with PHP authentication and PHP calls with JS authentication? If so- how do I get the token when Facebook says they're keeping track of things for me?